# React-Redux problem with getting clicked data on form for edit

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am writing a crud app with redux-react, My `Read` and `Create` operation is successfully is finished, they works great! Now I am trying to achive `edit` operation, I want when I click on edit button, the form should be filled the data I clicked on and also the form button name should be change in into `update`

this is my `table.js` file

```
import React, {Fragment} from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Table extends React.Component {

    onEdit (event, index) {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>EDIT</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.props.employees.map((item, index) => (
                    <tr key={index}>
                        <td>{item.name}</td>
                        <td>{item.age}</td>
                        <td>{item.email}</td>
                        <td>
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            onClick={(event) => this.onEdit(event, index)}
                            >EDIT
                        </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
                </tbody>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ employees: state.employees });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Table);
```

You may notice a button in table named `Edit` when i click on it, my form button should be changed `save` into `update` 
this is my `form.js` file:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react"
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {name: '', age: '', email: ''};
        this.onHandleChange = this.onHandleChange.bind(this);
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    }

    submit(event) {
        const data = {
            name: this.state.name, age: this.state.age, email: this.state.email
        };
        this.props.dispatch({type: 'ADD_POST', data})
    }

    onHandleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input onChange={(event) => this.onHandleChange(event)} value={this.state.name} name="name" type="text" />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <input onChange={(event) => this.onHandleChange(event)} value={this.state.age} name="age" type="number"/>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <input onChange={(event) => this.onHandleChange(event)} value={this.state.email}  name="email" type="text"/>
                </div>

                <button onClick={(event) => this.submit(event)} type="button">SAVE</button>

            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(null)(Form);
```

and this is my `postReducer.js` file:

```
var initialState = {
  employees: [{name: 'jhon', age: '23', email: 'a@a'}, {name: 'doe', age: '24', email: 'b@a'}] 
};

var postReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
      case 'ADD_POST':
        return {
          ...state,
          employees: [...state.employees, action.data],
        }
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };


export default postReducer;
```

and this is my `App.js` file:

```
import React from "react"
import Table from "./table"
import Form from '../components/form'

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>   
              <Form />          
            <table>
                <Table />
            </table>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

and this is my `index.js` file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./components/App";

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import { createStore } from 'redux'
import postReducer from '../src/postReducer'

const store = createStore(postReducer)


ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Can anyone please help me to achieve this? when I click on tables's edit button, the form should filled with clicked data and the form button should be changed into 'update'?

I tried a lot and failed, watched a lot of video,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a function in `App.js`, to get data from `Table` and send to `Form`.

Pass that function to your `Table`, and pass the data to `Form`.

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           selectedData: {name: '', age: '', email: ''},
           isEdit: false
        };
    }

    selectedData = (item) => {
       this.setState({selectedData: item,isEdit:true})
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>   
              <Form selectedData={this.state.selectedData} isEdit={this.state.isEdit}/>          
            <table>
                <Table selectedData={this.selectedData} />
            </table>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

In `Table` component, your `onEdit` function should be

```
onEdit = (item) => {  //Use arrow function to bind `this`
  this.props.selectedData(item);
}
```

And for button, you should only pass selected data

```
<button
    type="button"
    onClick={() => this.onEdit(item)}
>
    EDIT
</button>
```

In `Form` component, your `state` should get data from `props`

```
this.state = {name: this.props.selectedData.name, age: this.props.selectedData.age, email: this.props.selectedData.email}
```

You should have `componentDidUpdate` method to handle next `props`,

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
   if(prevProps.selectedData.email !== this.props.selectedData.email){  //Check on email, because email is unique
     this.setState({name: this.props.selectedData.name, age: this.props.selectedData.age, email: this.props.selectedData.email})
   }
}
```

And your button should be,

```
<button onClick={(event) => this.submit(event)} type="button">
   {this.props.isEdit ? 'Update' : 'SAVE' }
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, Your time is much appreciated, you made day